# HAProxy with SSL Termination and HTTP/2 in Go

Tags: ssl, go, haproxy, http2

I have a web application written in Go and load balanced by HAProxy. HAProxy also handles SSL/TLS termination. Currently the responses are all HTTP/1.1 and I'd like them to be HTTP/2. I've tried various things in haproxy.conf, but haven't been able to get it working.

I'm able to get a standalone Go server that handles its own SSL termination to use HTTP/2, but it looks like all current browsers only support HTTP/2 over TLS. Does this mean that I need to handle the SSL termination at the web app itself? Or is there some workaround that I don't know about so that I can continue terminating SSL at the load balancer and still use HTTP/2?

It looks like this is impossible, but I'm hoping there is a way to do it since otherwise I need to deal with SSL certificates at each web application rather than just at the load balancer.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by having the backend connection be http/2? Nothing supports http/2 without tls, so you would have to handle tls no matter what.

Comment: Right @JimB but this look like a question about where in the stack the TLS can be offloaded -- it needn't be on the app server, it can be in front of that.

Comment: @JeffRogers this is of course a configuration that should work, but HAProxy can't yet speak h2 so it has to be in `mode tcp`, which disables a lot of its capabilities and it can no longer make any routing decisions.  Is that the part you're missing?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to offload TLS to the load balancer so that I can manage all the SSL certs in one place, but it sounds like I'd have to switch to nginx or something else to do this at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or is there some workaround that I don't know about so that I can continue terminating SSL at the load balancer and still use HTTP/2?

If I've got you right, you need a HTTP/2 aware load balancer which can proxy your requests to your application. You may use [nginx](http://nginx.org). It can excellent do [http2 termination](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html), load balancing and many other things. So probably you may not need haproxy at all. However haproxy is useful if you want some advanced features like sticky sessions. Nginx also can do them, but only in a commercial version.

Here's an article (in Google cache) how to [setup nginx + haproxy](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KCw-Spv2h-YJ:m12.io/blog/http-2-with-haproxy-and-nginx-guide%3Futm_content%3Dbufferce461%26amp%3Butm_medium%3Dsocial%26amp%3Butm_source%3Dtwitter.com%26amp%3Butm_campaign%3Dbuffer%3Fref%3Dupflow.co%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ru).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do. I was hoping to keep using HAProxy because I'm familiar with it already and it's working well for me. I'll leave this question open a little longer to see if anyone else has any thoughts and accept this otherwise.

Comment: I thought you can use them together. Nginx as a h2 terminator which just proxies anything to haproxy and it do "all magic stuff".